# How to declare variable in function arguments

Tags: c, gcc

I need to declare a variable inside function arguments. Please advice the syntax to use?

I've got something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo (int *a)
{
   printf ("%d\n", *a);
}

int main (void)
{
   foo (&(int){int a=1});
   return 0;
}
```

And GCC fails with the message:

```
$ gcc a.c
a.c: In function 'main':
a.c:10: error: expected expression before '{' token
```

As an option I can put use not named variable like this ([same question at russian version of Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777826/221676)):

```
foo(&(int) { 1 });
```

and it works, but it is interesting why compiler accept `{1}` but does not accept `{int a=1}`

Comment: What do you mean by *"declare it as a variable but not as a constant"*?

Comment: Why do you need this ?

Comment: 'as a variable' means something like `{int a=1}`, not like just `{1}`. Sorry if I ask stupid questions.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? I fail to see what advantage this has over `int a = 1; foo(&a);`

Comment: I need this by 2 reasons. First - in my project I need to call API function from macros and pass pointer to variable that I really do not use. And to simplify macros I prefer to write all in one line without complex solutions like `#define CALL_FOO() do {int a=1; foo(&a);}while(0)`
Second reason - I would like to understand better how compiler works. I have seen such solution preciously in internet, just cannot remind the syntax and cannot find it again. And knowing the solution will bring me better understanding how compiler understands `{}` and variables visability

Comment: Again, what purpose to you envision that `a` having, assuming you could declare it?

Comment: @PeterK.: It's possible you're after something called *statement expressions* which is a gcc extension. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html. It's not standard C though.

Comment: @Bathsheba - Keeping my fingers crossed for C20 :)

Comment: Since you know about the compound literal notation, and your `&(int){int a = 1}` notation seems to be trying to use it too, it isn't clear what you're hoping for.  You can't define a variable name inside the compound literal.  It really isn't clear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use compound literal - I suspect that's what you tried, you almost got it right:

```
foo (&(int){1});
```

This is by no means a "constant", I don't know how you got that idea.

Note that a compound literal only have local ("automatic") storage duration - if the calling block goes out of scope, so does the compound literal.

Comment: Yes, this variant works (as in description). And sorry - I've used wrong terms. You are correct - `{1}` here is not a "constant" - as I understoot it is just a variable on stack that has no name. My question was how to give a name to this variable. If I try to set `{int a=1}` instead of just `{1}` the gcc prints error. I just do not understand how compiler treat this construction and why does it suppose it as an error.

Comment: @PeterK. Why on earth do you need to _name_ a variable, when in this case **the name is only useful from the point where the variable is created until the function is called**? Once inside a function, the variable name is that of the pointer parameter. Your explanation about writing all of this in comments doesn't make sense. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if I ever saw one.

Comment: ok, accept this answer (even having it in my initial comment) because it actually resolve my request 'to have declaration inside argument'. Again, I would like to understand why compiler suppose that `{int a=1}` and just `{1}` are different.